# FCM doesn't work after enabling Proguard in gradle

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, proguard

I connected `FCM` and tested before. And it worked fine.

However, I am ready to publish my app and enabled `proguard` in `build.gradle`

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            proguardFile 'proguard_debug.pro'
        }
    }
```

And applied this in `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform
```

Everyone get push messages but just my test phone doesn't receive them which is `proguard` enabled. I converted my `data` models to `Serialize` format. But now this problem is happening.

How can I use FCM or other Firebase features such as `Remote Config` or `Crashlystics`?

Comment: `data` models is Kotlin `data` class?

Comment: it was `data class` but changed it to `class MyClass: Serializable` and then gave `@SerializedName('variable_name')` for each variables and solved serializing problem. But It's another problem. I am having a problem with `FCM` now.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation renames variables in Kotlin `data class` without `@SerializedName` and as result `Json` not parsing to model class.
To prevent this you can use `@Keep` annotation

```
@Keep
data class MyClass(...)
```

or set `@SerializedName` to all values

Comment: Thanks. But.. Do you have any ideas for `FCM`?

Comment: @c-an You can add `-dontnote com.google.**` to `proguard-rules.pro` But i'm not using any specific configuration with `Firebase`

Comment: Do I need to implement `Serializable`?